# Create MySQL database via Linux terminal and connect it via phpMyAdmin

Tags: mysql, linux, azure, phpmyadmin

I am trying to migrate my database to Azure host. To do it, I did create a Linux Ububtu virtual machine on Azure host. Then, I did access the virtual machine via SSH and installed MySQL server. So, I created a database "ficabelo" and a user to this database.

How can I access and manager this database using phpMyAdmin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I access and manager this database using phpMyAdmin?

Do you mean you install Mysql on **Azure VM**, and you want install `phpmyadmin` on this VM to manage your Mysql database?

If yes, we can do this same as on-premise, install LAMP on Azure VM and configure `phpmyadmin` to this VM.

If you want to use `phpmyadmin` to manage your mysql database over the internet, we should open port 80 on Azure NSG, **add port 80 to NSG's inbound rules**, so we can browse it from the internet.

I had install LAMP and phpmyadmin on Azure ubuntu VM, and add port 80 to NSG inbound rules, it works for me:

[image]

More information about how to configure phpmyadm on ubuntu, please refer to those links below:

[How to install LAMP on ubuntu](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-linux-apache-mysql-php-lamp-stack-on-ubuntu-14-04).

[Install and Secure phpMyAdmin on Ubuntu](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-secure-phpmyadmin-on-ubuntu-14-04)

Azure VM NSG setting:

[image]